# Converting JSON file into postgresql, avoid duplicates

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I am working on a set of scripts in Postgresql to put my JSON files into tables.

I know Postgresql can parse JSON but I want to do statistics, join between distinct kinds of objects, ...

Thanks to several githubs, I made up a SQL function who can give all attributes within the object. It's recursive, and it's handling tables :

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION listAttribut1Job(jobID integer) 
RETURNS Void as
$BODY$
DECLARE
    result attributeJob;
BEGIN
WITH RECURSIVE doc_key_and_value_recursive(key, value) AS (
  SELECT
    t.key,
    t.value
  FROM jobs, json_each(jobs.job) AS t WHERE jobs.id=jobID

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    CONCAT(doc_key_and_value_recursive.key, $$__$$, t.key),
    CASE
        WHEN json_typeof(t.value) = 'array' 
        THEN json_array_elements(t.value)
        ELSE t.value
    END
  FROM doc_key_and_value_recursive,
    json_each(
        CASE 
        WHEN json_typeof(doc_key_and_value_recursive.value) <> 'object' THEN '{}' :: JSON
        ELSE doc_key_and_value_recursive.value
    END) AS t
)
INSERT INTO jobsAttributeFullList(
    SELECT jobID,REPLACE(key,'.','_'),value      --respect des noms dans pgsql : pas de . ni de -> dans les column names
    FROM doc_key_and_value_recursive
    WHERE json_typeof(doc_key_and_value_recursive.value) <> 'object'
    );
END
$BODY$
language 'plpgsql' ;
```

Then I have a table like :

```
ObjectID | AttributeName     | AttributeValue
---------|-------------------|------------
1        | SomeName          | SomeValue
2        | SomeName(same)    | AnotherValue
```

Which is what I want. My problem is : how to avoid duplicates when I have arrays?
For example, if my JSON is like :

```
 {"param":[
              {"name":"parm1","value":"CSR"},
              {"name":"parm2","value":"C"},
              {"name":"parm3","value":"IFRS"}]}
```

My function will give me :

```
id; AttributeName            | value
1|"job__params__param__name" |""parm3""
1|"job__params__param__name" |""parm2""
1|"job__params__param__name" |""parm1""
1|"job__params__param__value"|""IFRS""
1|"job__params__param__value"|""CSR""
1|"job__params__param__value"|""C""
```

I would to have something like

```
id; AttributeName            | value
1|"job__params__param3__name" |""parm3""
1|"job__params__param2__name" |""parm2""
1|"job__params__param1__name" |""parm1""
1|"job__params__param3__value"|""IFRS""
1|"job__params__param2__value"|""CSR""
1|"job__params__param1__value"|""C""
```

So I tried things like 'IF attribute name IN (SELECT Attribute from ...) but it does not work.

I am using the function above in this context:

```
OPEN jobCursor FOR (SELECT id FROM jobsJSON); -- 
    LOOP
        FETCH jobCursor INTO record_job;
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
        PERFORM listAttribut1Job(record_job.jobID);
    END LOOP;
```

(my objects are called jobs). Of course, I can modify this context.

Would you know a way to do something like 
'IF attribute ALREADY IN attributeTable THEN attribute:=attribute1' or attribute2 if attribute1 si used, or ... ?

Thank you very much

PS: If you want full code I can give it, I just wanted the post to be easy to read.

Comment: I tried to do some update once the table containing attributes is created. But I could nt know which value match with parm1 or parm2 or ...

Comment: Sorry if my comment is not constructive (I maybe don't have enough skills to properly answer your question) but wouldn't it be worth using a document-oriented DB such as MongoDB to store data from JSON files? Or let the client application (written in C#, Java, Python...) do such a task?

Comment: I use PGSql because I would like to do lots of statistics, jointure, .... And I thought SQL was the best way to do so. 
The file is generated by a php function, I think I am going to modify it to update my datas. Indeed, working in the client application looks like a good idea

Comment: It looks easier to me but must admit I am not from the SQL world (well not that much). Parsing JSON and handling objects are easier in OO languages.

Comment: With a relevant part of the source data it might be possible to suggest a saner approach.

Comment: I tried PHP but I am not skilled enough so I chose china farmer strategy and created a very big and heavy script ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I tried to update client application but I'm too lame at PHP so I created a big script to avoid duplicates. Feel free to upgrade it and to comment if you know how to make it better:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION avoidDuplicateJobs(jobID integer)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
queryString varchar;
queryStringGroup varchar;
newAN varchar;
dupsCursor REFCURSOR;
dupsNameCursor REFCURSOR;
dupsR RECORD;
NameR RECORD;
IDR RECORD;
indice integer;
BEGIN
    queryString :=('SELECT attribID, jobID, attributeName,value from jobsAttributeFullList jAFL '
    ||'where (select count(*) from jobsAttributeFullList jAFL2 '
    ||'where jobid='||jobID||' AND '
    ||'jAFL.attributeName = jAFL2.attributename) >1 '
    ||' AND jobid='||jobID
    ||' ORDER BY attributename, attribid  ');
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dups;
    CREATE TEMP TABLE dups(attribID integer, jobID integer , attributeName varchar(100) NOT NULL, value varchar); 
    --RAISE INFO 'Query : %',queryString;
--  INSERT INTO dups (attribID, jobID, attributeName,value) 
    OPEN dupsCURSOR FOR EXECUTE (queryString);
    --EXECUTE queryString INTO dupsCursor;
    --OPEN dupsNameCursor FOR(SELECT attributeName FROM dupsCursor GROUP BY attributeName);
    LOOP 
        FETCH dupsCursor INTO dupsR;
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
        --RAISE INFO 'dups = %' ,dupsR;
        INSERT  INTO dups (attribID, jobID, attributeName,value) VALUES (dupsR.attribID,dupsR.jobID, dupsR.attributeName, dupsR.value) ;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE dupsCURSOR;
    OPEN dupsNameCursor FOR (SELECT DISTINCT attributeName FROM dups);
    LOOP
        FETCH dupsNameCursor INTO NameR;
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
        RAISE INFO 'attributeName = %' ,NameR;
        indice:=0;
        queryStringGroup:='SELECT attribID FROM dups where attributename ='||$$'$$||NameR.attributeName||$$'$$||' ORDER BY attribid;';
        OPEN dupsCURSOR FOR EXECUTE queryStringGroup;
        LOOP
            FETCH dupsCursor INTO IDR;
            EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
            RAISE INFO 'attribID =%',IDR;
            indice:=indice +1;
            queryString:= ('SELECT attributeName FROM dups WHERE attribID='||IDR.attribID);
            EXECUTE queryString INTO newAN;
            newAN:=newAN||indice;
            RAISE INFO 'newAN = %', newAN;
            queryString:= $$UPDATE jobsattributefulllist SET attributeName='$$||newAN||$$' WHERE attribID=$$||IDR.attribID||' ;';
            RAISE INFO 'Update Query = %',queryString;
            EXECUTE queryString;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE dupsCURSOR;

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE dupsNameCursor;


END;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```